# How to hide the record selector arrow of the XamDataGrid without hiding the record index?

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics

On the picture below the record selector arrow is displayed on the left of the record index:

[image]

I tryed to set the **RecordSelectorLocation** property of the XamDataGrid control to *None*

```
XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings.RecordSelectorLocation = RecordSelectorLocation.None;
```

In this case the record number is disappearing too, but I would like to display it.

How can I hide the record selector arrow of the XamDataGrid without hiding the record index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*With compliments to Infragistics support the following solution was suggested.*

In order to hide the record selector arrow of the XamDataGrid without hiding the record index it is recommended to re-template the RecordSelector element to only include the record numbering element. The following style and template can be used to achieve this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:RecordSelector}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <igDP:RecordSelectorNumber HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```